# Getting exception while sending email through Amazon SES

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, console, amazon-ses

Getting the below exception while trying to send email through Amazon AWS SMTP credentials..Previously it was working fine using Gmail SMTP credential..
Here i am using console app for sending email.
And i have already requested for  Suppression List Removal in Amazon Portal ..It was successfully removed ..Still getting the same issue.
Exception Detail :
Transaction failed. The server response was: Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: xyz@outlook.com, abc@metaoption.com

Answer (score 1):

Until the email addresses are verified, you will not be able to send email to those addresses because your SES is account is in sandbox (free) mode.

Go to AWS SES console and click on Email Addresses on the left pane.

[image]

Then click on Verify a New Email Address and enter the email you want to verify. Once you receive the email, click on the link in the email to verify the email.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you first start using SES, your account is in sandbox mode.

That means you need to verify the email addresses or domains you want to test with.  So in your case, you need to set up xyz@outlook.com and abc@metaoption.com before you can send them email.